# NavigationController.toolbar.frame doesn't work immediately

Tags: ios, uitableview

In `viewWillLayoutSubviews` I set a different height for `NavigationController.toolbar.frame` depending on whether the `UITableView` is in the edit mode or not. I also ensure that it gets called then by calling `layoutIfNeeded()` (and it does - checked both by the debugger and the fact that its subviews are layout different as they should according to the code).

However, the problem is that the height is not changed to lower immediately (but it works without the problem when changing back to the higher height). It does get smaller only after scrolling the table fast.

I guess this is some kind of bug, but whether someone can recommend some sort of a workaround?

Comment: Share your code, it's impossible to help you fix it otherwise. Also calling `layoutIfNeeded()` sometimes help with these kind of issues.

Comment: @deadbeef You have all necessary details in the code above. Unless if you think that it is important whether the new height of the frame is 40 or 30, it ain't secret I can share that just I can't see the point. layoutIfNeeded is called, I could have been more specific with that I guess, I'll update the question to reflect that.